# Ef Core - auditing changes and including navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, change-tracking, audit-trail

We need to implement a comprehensive audit log of changes for an aggregate entity called Project, where users can see what changed with each save and the before and after values of those changes. The entity contains a few child collections (for example a collection of TeamMember entities).

There are options like EF Plus (http://entityframework-plus.net/) which manages the audit for you or we could override EFs savechanges() and write to our own audit table manually.

Where things get tricky are where you have a navigation property. Any child collections such as TeamMembers are seen as a separate entry in the change tracker and therefore would be logged as an update independently of project. We need to be able to track all changes for a specific project i.e. anything that has changed within that object graph.

Having searched quite exhaustively online, we are at a bit of loss as to what to try. The option we are looking at now is serialising into JSON the whole Project entity, prior to and after save, into an audit log. We then need to write some custom comparison logic to see whats changed and return that to the UI. This seems like unnecessary complexity.

If anyone in the community has done this before and has a good approach or any ideas here it would be of great help.

Comment: We are for now going to write some custom comparison logic to get us over this sprint. This will serialise both the before and after Project json and then compare each field manually building up a list of changes that are user friendly, so that it can be return the front end.

Comment: I'm also have the same task. Tried to find some built-in solution for this, but with not much success :(
For now, I've added a method to my Repository class which looks into `context.Entry(entity).Members`, trying to extract changes from there. 
Have you find solution? Can you share some knowledge? :)

Comment: Hi. As above we ended up implementing our own audit on Save.  We store a serialized json representation of the entity being saved before and after the update. To display the audit history on the page to the end user we have written a function that manually compares the two deserialised objects and builds up a user friendly list of changes. It was the easiest way to fully support our requirements. What is it you need to show to the end user? Anf what version of EF are you using?

Comment: hi @Amay, I'm not showing anything to end-user, I need it to log changes and add ability to implement "discard changes" aka "undo".
For now, I've wrote a small extension to ChangeTracker, which returns me a list of changes (recursively). https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/12335 here you can see that piece of code. But there are bug in EF, it's don't mark collections as changed. I'm not in a hurry, so I'll wait for a fix :)
Thanks you anyway ;)

Comment: @Amay how are you checking if an EntityEntry (from ChangeTracker) is your aggregate root or top most parent? We're looking to do the same thing as you by capturing the top most parent and saving the entire log for that root